# ¿Como ordenar un jTable a partir de un boton?

Tags: java, jtable, ordenamiento, jbutton

Hola estoy creando un programa donde  voy registrando los puntos que gana una persona por ronda, mi problema es que al pasar de ronda quiero organizar mi `jTable` de la mejor puntuación a la peor pero no he encontrado como hacerlo a partir de un botón, solo me aparece como hacerlo desde la cabecera del `jtable` o desde que inicia el programa.
estos son los bloques de código con los que creo la tabla

```
private DefaultTableModel Tablaaux1(){

       DT3 = new DefaultTableModel ();
     DT3.addColumn("Num. de Identificacion");
      DT3.addColumn("Nombre");
      DT3.addColumn("Puntuacion");
      //DT3.addColumn("Ciudad");
      return DT3;
    }
```

y este:

```
private void listarparticipantesronda (){

       jTable3.setModel(Tablaaux1());
    }
```

y quisiera que a partir de un `jbutton` llamado terminar ronda mi `jtable` pueda `organizarce` de mejor puntuación a peor, gracias por su atención.

Comment: Como gestionas los puntos por ronda?

Comment: gracias por responder, al comenzar la primera ronda todos empiezan con 0 puntos y al seleccionar una fila, seleccionar un radio Burton (victoria, derrota o empate) y dar click en un botón le doy sus respectivos puntos según el radio Burton seleccionado actualizando así su puntuación en el jtable

Comment: Entonces, al apretar un botón..quieres ordenar/actualizar la tabla a partir de la columna puntuación?

Comment: Asi es, para asi poder avanzar en las rondas